# EF6 to load specified child entities per Query

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I have a class with a method to retrieve data from SQLite database using EF6.

The *context* is being injected in the constructor and there for the **same** context is being used multiple times for the same class instance. I am using the `Include` extension method for Entity Framework 6 to include child entities in a query. The item to be included is specified in a parameter and can thus change depending on the callers requirements.

Here is a sample of the class:

```
public class AccountManager
{
    private SQLiteContext context;

    // Injected Context
    public AccountManager(SQLiteContext Context)
    {
        context = Context;
    }

    public Account GetAccountById(int AccountId, string ToInclude)
    {
        return context.Account
                      .Include(ToInclude)
                      .Single(a => a.AccountId == AccountId)
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I include a child entity in my first query (Query A) it works correctly, but if I include a **different** child entity in a subsequent query (using the same *context*) the child entity of Query A is also included. For example:

```
AccountManager am = new AccountManager(MyContext);

// Run first query
var a1 = am.GetAccountById(1, "Payments");

// Run second query
// The result of this query also includes child entity "Payments" 
// because it was added to the context in the previous query
var a2 = am.GetAccountById(1, "Owners");
```

Is there a way that I can prevent this from happening and that the 'Include' setting of every query is uniquely processed?

Comment: When using the same context: only by detaching the payments from the context. Or fetch the data with `AsNoTracking()`.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer (If you change it as an answer I will flag it as the correct one) - The 'AccountManager' class should be instantiated each time for each piece of "work" so that the context can track accordingly. The class will sit behind a WCF service eventually so the problem will solve itself (Each request will create a new context). But at the moment it is a _DataService_ part of a MVVM (Light) project so the IOC instantiates the class once and is re-used by all other VM's. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Entity Framework grabs entities from the database, the default behavior is that it adds the entities to its change tracker. The change tracker doesn't only track changes to individual entities, but also to associations. Therefore, EF also populates any navigation properties it can find by entities in its change tracker cache.

So when you fetch the accounts with owners, EF will still find the belonging payments and populate `account.Payments` wherever possible, whether you like it or not.

I think in your case, the best you can do is to fetch the entities without tracking:

```
return context.Account.AsNoTracking()
              .Include(ToInclude)
              .Single(a => a.AccountId == AccountId)
```

Now EF will populate the `Payments` or the `Owners`, but not add these entities to its cache. In an N-tier application, in most cases it's better to use `AsNoTracking`, because hardly ever are changes applied to entities in the context by which they were read and `AsNoTracking` performs better, because updating the change tracker and relationship fixup are expensive processes.

Alternatively, you can mark entities as `EntityState.Detached`, but I wouldn't go that path.

The best way is to use a new context for each business transaction, so it's good that you're developing into that direction.

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT: If you have a relation of one to many, I wouldn't recommend you to do that. It's very expensive. I'd rather create two different queries.**

But, if you want to do that, I think a better option could be make a dynamic query, is very usefull. Something like that:

```
    public Account GetAccountById(int AccountId, bool includePayments = false, bool includeOwners)
  {
        var query = context.Account;

      if(includePayments)
      {
         query = query.Include(c => c.Payments).AsQueryable()
      }

      if(includeOwners)
      {
         query = query.Include(c => c.Owners).AsQueryable()
      }

      return  query.Single(a => a.AccountId == AccountId)
}
```

Comment: Read carefully. This is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually an optimisation of Entity frameworks doing this for you.

Entity frameworks is building a data-tree as queries are executed.

It is worth asking yourself why you would want to exclude this information at all.